# How do I create the equation for a parabola in 3-space when I know several points on the parabola and the vertex?

Tags: conic-sections, 3d

I'm attempting to find the equation for a parabola in 3-space.  I have several points on the curve (I can get more if necessary):
    (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>)
    (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, z<sub>2</sub>)
    (x<sub>3</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>, z<sub>3</sub>)
    (x<sub>4</sub>, y<sub>4</sub>, z<sub>4</sub>)
and I have the vertex (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub>).

I've seen some (not much) information about defining it with parametric equations, but I'd really like to have it as a Cartesian equation if at all possible.

How would I go about taking this information and converting it into an equation?  I've tried converting it into a plane, and while successful, it didn't really accomplish my goal.

If there's other information I need to do this, let me know.  There are other properties I can probably get.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Sub

Comment: You might be out of luck. Any curve in three dimensions, be it planar like a parabola or non-planar like a helix, cannot be described with a single implicit function. Those objects that can be represented by a single equation are always two-dimensional, like ellipsoids and hyperboloids.

Comment: The parabola is going to be contained in a plane, since it is supposed to be the intersection of a plane and a cone. With three of the points you an compute a linear equation that defines that plane. For example, $det[[x_1,y_1,z_1,1],[x_2,y_2,z_2,1],[x_3,y_3,z_3,1],[x,y,z,1]]=0$ is one such equation. We need another equation, which could be the equation of a cone, or of a parabolic cylinder.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I have constructed the plane the parabola lives in by creating two vectors in the plane using my points and then obtaining the cross product. I plugged in one point and got my plane.  I was really hoping there was a 3d analog of the 2d equation.  I guess I'll have to use parametrics.

Comment: What if I wanted to create a paraboloid of revolution using the above information?

Comment: user463383 - I have a hyperbolic paraboloid that the plane intersects to give the parabola.  How can I use the equation of the plane and the equation of the hyperbolic paraboloid to get the equation I'm looking for?  Just solve as a system of equations?